# Linear least squares regression with a smoothness penalty vs linear regression with ARIMA errors

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, autoregressive, regularization

I am about to choose between the two options mentioned in the title and I am not really sure what to pick.

As a first option, we have classical linear regression plus a smoothness penalty, i.e., 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{minimize} \sum_{t=1}^T ( y_t - {\bf x}_t^{\mathrm T} {\bf \beta} - s_t )^2 + \lambda \sum_{t=2}^T (s_t - s_{t-1})^2 
\end{equation}
which is to be minimized over $\beta$ and $\{s_t\}_{t=1}^T$ and parameter $\lambda$ can be chosen through cross-validation.

As a second option, we have linear regression with ARIMA errors, i.e., assume that 
\begin{equation}
y_t = {\bf x}_t^{\mathrm T} {\bf \beta} + u_t 
\end{equation}
where $u_t$ is an ARIMA process.

It seems to me that the ARIMA approach is more reasonable, but I am a bit confused: Can the smoothness term in the first case be made to account for correlated residuals? Is there an example of nasty residual process that can be captured by the ARIMA assumption while not captured by the smoothness assumption?

Comment: What is the $s_t$? How does it work? Do we know how $s_t$ evolves over time?

Comment: introducing $s_t$ is an attempt to capture an effect such as a long term trend that would otherwise lead to erroneous estimation of betas. other than smoothness, I do not impose any requirement on $s_t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linear least squares regression with a smoothness penalty could capture positive autocorrelation in errors (which forms a smooth pattern, like several negative errors in a row followed by several positive errors in a row), but it would not naturally fit negative autocorrelation (where the errors have frequently altering signs).

Meanwhile, linear regression with ARIMA errors could fit both positively and negatively autocorrelated errors, as the ARIMA errors part is quite flexible. Moreover, ARIMA errors have an explicit structure and are predictable, which seems more useful than having a smooth trend $s_t$ with no definite pattern in it (unless you later model the estimated $s_t$ on its own).

Comment: I do not intend to model $s_t$ on its own after the fit. I agree with your opinion and I vote for it. I guess that the final choice depends also on the data that you are dealing with (i.e., if you know a-priori that your time series y_t decomposes into a smoothly varying component and a linear regression part then the first model becomes more appropriate - but of course, I do not have such evidence). Unless I hear some more opinions, I will go with the ARIMA approach. Thank you for taking the time to answer my dilema!

Comment: Great! Although you have not actually voted :)

Comment: I was afraid that by voting I am excluding the topic for further exploration  and (even though a great answer) I think it deserves discussion